# Mandelbrot Set function crashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, set, mandelbrot

i made a sim for the Mandelbrot Set function, zn + 1 = power(zn) + c
and it work but when i get to the point were the function is unstable it crashes, now i have a boolen that when true makes a wire that connects all the circles, when its false its fine(dosent crash) but when its on it does, the code works like this:

start:
building a list of circles and making there pos by the equation, and then crating a wire between the circle and the last circle,
update:
then when you move the circle it uses the already made list of gameobj to update there pos.

you can try it here:
[build](https://play.unity.com/mg/other/builds-mj-2)
github:
[git](https://github.com/Evyatar22/Mandelbrot-Set-function.git)

but it crashes:(, heres the code:

```
 private void updateCircles()
{
    StartUpdateCircles();
}


private void StartCircles()
{
    float x = BlackCircle.anchoredPosition.x;
    float y = BlackCircle.anchoredPosition.y;
    AllCircles.Add(BlackCircle.gameObject);

    for (int i = 1; i < itarations; i++)
    {
        Vector2 RedCircleVec2 = RedCircle.anchoredPosition;
        Vector2 LastCircleVec2 = AllCircles[i - 1].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
        GameObject Circle = Instantiate(BlackCircle.gameObject, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

        Circle.transform.SetParent(CanvasPerent);
        AllCircles.Add(Circle);

        x = Mathf.Pow(x, 2);
        x -= Mathf.Pow(LastCircleVec2.y, 2);
        x += RedCircleVec2.x;

        y = (2 * LastCircleVec2.x
            * LastCircleVec2.y) + RedCircleVec2.y;

        Circle.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);

        if (HasWire)
        {
             GameObject wire = GenrateWireStart(LastCircleVec2
           , Circle.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition);

            AllWires.Add(wire);
        }

    }

}

private void StartUpdateCircles()
{
    float x = BlackCircle.anchoredPosition.x;
    float y = BlackCircle.anchoredPosition.y;
    for (int i = 1; i < itarations; i++)
    {
        Vector2 RedCircleVec2 = RedCircle.anchoredPosition;
        Vector2 LastCircleVec2 = AllCircles[i - 1].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
        RectTransform ICircle = AllCircles[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>();


        x = Mathf.Pow(x, 2);
        x -= Mathf.Pow(LastCircleVec2.y, 2);
        x += RedCircleVec2.x;

        y = (2 * LastCircleVec2.x
            * LastCircleVec2.y) + RedCircleVec2.y;

        ICircle.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
        if (HasWire)
        {
            
              GenrateWireUpdate(LastCircleVec2
                ,ICircle.anchoredPosition, i);
            
            
        }
    }
}

public GameObject GenrateWireStart(Vector2 NodeA, Vector2 NodeB)
{
    GameObject Connector = new GameObject("connector", typeof(Image));
    Connector.transform.SetParent(CanvasPerent);
    RectTransform ConnectorRT = Connector.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    ConnectorRT.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    ConnectorRT.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 0);

    Connector.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.25f);

    Vector2 dir = (NodeB - NodeA).normalized;
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(NodeA, NodeB);

    ConnectorRT.sizeDelta = new Vector2(distance, 0.005f);

    ConnectorRT.position = NodeA + dir * distance * .5f;

    ConnectorRT.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, UtilsClass.GetAngleFromVectorFloat(dir));

    return Connector;
}

public void GenrateWireUpdate(Vector2 NodeA, Vector2 NodeB, int i)
{
    RectTransform ConnectorRT = AllWires[i - 1].GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    Vector2 dir = (NodeB - NodeA).normalized;
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(NodeA, NodeB);
    ConnectorRT.sizeDelta = new Vector2(distance, 0.005f);
    ConnectorRT.position = NodeA + dir * distance * .5f;
    ConnectorRT.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, UtilsClass.GetAngleFromVectorFloat(dir));
}
```

pls help, thank you.

[image: the project]

Comment: Could you add how exactly you call these methods? They are all private and no Unity messages so I guess it might be relevant to see how you call them. Also by "crashing" you mean it freezes or do you get any errors?

Comment: If you post a link to your build .. could you explain what we are looking at, how we are supposed to interact with it and how exactly your issue is reproduced?

Comment: What I can say for now you are getting an error `An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was:
RuntimeError: integer overflow` which sounds pretty self-explanatory: Some `int` is growing bigger than `2147483647` .. I think you should rather [debug your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and check when exactly this happens in the editor where you can still fully debug ;)

Comment: mmm, okay thanks for the idea, i will chack to see if i can fix the issue

Comment: i will make a GitHub repository just a sec

Comment: https://github.com/Evyatar22/Mandelbrot-Set-function/tree/main/Mandelbrot%20Set/Assets%20and%20Code

Comment: In general assuming this is a Unity project you are not allowed to rename the `Assets` folder to something else ;)

Comment: thanks i was wandring why it wasent opening

Comment: Also in general you repo is broken ^^ The scripts in the scene are all missing (I can somehow guess to a certain extend what goes where - but all references are lost)

Comment: yes i saw i will update it sorry :(, but seriously thanks for the help

Comment: https://github.com/Evyatar22/Mandelbrot-Set-function.git

Comment: works?, sorry im new to github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked briefly into your code and you seem to get some invalid positions like infinite / undefined from your calculations or just some positions too far away for Unity.

I could remove these by simply limiting positions to e.g.

```
 x = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.Pow(x, 2), -Screen.width, Screen.width);
 x = Mathf.Clamp(x - Mathf.Pow(LastCircleVec2.y, 2), -Screen.width, Screen.width);
 x = Mathf.Clamp(x + RedCircleVec2.x, -Screen.width, Screen.width);

 y = Mathf.Clamp((2 * LastCircleVec2.x * LastCircleVec2.y) + RedCircleVec2.y, -Screen.width, Screen.width);
```

which simply limits all positions to some off-screen max positions

Comment: thanks man, it works now!, much apricated!

Comment: so you basically made it go only to a certain range? before it was going infinite and it caused the overflow?

Comment: @billthecomputerwiz exactly .. I clamped it at an arbitrary value .. just making sure for now it is somewhere out of the screen to not look awkward ;)

Comment: @billthecomputerwiz I would have some refactoring suggestions and fixes for the drag and animator behavior btw ;) I created a PR you can take it or ignore it ^^

Comment: thanks, i will implement some of your code, just curious, have you ever programed this function or the Mandelbrot set?

Comment: @billthecomputerwiz hehe no I haven't ;)